# Keyboard bouncing with @FocusState and .onSubmit

Tags: swift, swiftui, keyboard

I'm trying to implement `@FocusState` in my app to improve the login flow. Actually the code works fine but every time `.onSubmit` is triggered the keyboard bounce. I don't understand if I'm doing something wrong or it's a bug.

```
    struct FocusedFieldTest: View {
    enum FocusedField {
        case username, password, email
    }
    
    @FocusState private var focusedField: FocusedField?
    
    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var username = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                TextField("Enter your email", text: $email)
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: .email)
                    .submitLabel(.continue)
                
                TextField("Enter your username", text: $username)
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: .username)
                    .submitLabel(.continue)
                
                SecureField("Enter your password", text: $password)
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: .password)
                    .submitLabel(.done)
            }
            .onSubmit {
                switch focusedField {
                case .email:
                    focusedField = .username
                case .username:
                    focusedField = .password
                default:
                    focusedField = nil
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Test")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you find any work around for this? @Gaspare

Comment: I haven't found any solution.

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue, I'm assuming it's a bug/"feature" of Apple considering like me you have the same code as found in the Apple Docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/focusstate

Comment: Still seeing the same issue in iOS 16.2.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in iOS 16, it's been happening since the first betas. Your approach is correct. You can try running the same thing on iOS 15, it will work just as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem with iOS 16. Solved it by changing the focusState strategy to use an enum like this

```swift
private enum FocusField: Hashable {
    case focusField1
    case focusField2
  }

  @FocusState private var focusedField: FocusField?
```

And then on the View

```swift
TextField("", value: $field1)
  .focused($focusedField, equals: .focusField1)

.onAppear {
  focusedField = .focusField1          
}
```

You can find the documentation and more complete example here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/focusstate

Comment: My code is identical to yours and the keyboard bounce is still happening for me. I do not think it's related to enum vs. boolean usage.

Comment: thanks for the great solution. It is fixed eventually.

Comment: I tried the code on iOS 16.4 and the keyboard still bounced

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and resolved it so far. I changed to a List with a plain listStyle. I used the FocusState property wrapper as a Bool type and added the focused modifier to my TextField. I added the toolbar modifier below that toggles the FocusState as well.

```
.toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
                Button("Dismiss") {
                    focusField.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
```